# C++/IOS Websockets using the Poco Library

Tags: c++, ios, poco, poco-libraries

I've recently started using the Poco library (which I think is great) and I'm trying to create an Server to connect too using an ios application using socket.io - websocket's. I've managed to use an node js implementation to connect but require a C++ implementation. I've stated by instantiating the websocket within the handleRequest method but unsure to what the next steps are...

Any help would be very much appreciated..

```
virtual void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest &req, HTTPServerResponse &resp)
{
   char buffer[16384];

   WebSocket* ws = new WebSocket(req, resp);
   //ws->setKeepAlive(false);
   int flags;
   if (!ws->poll(500,Poco::Net::Socket::SELECT_READ || Poco::Net::Socket::SELECT_ERROR))
   {   
      cout << ".";
   }   
   else
   {   
       int n = ws->receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
       if (n > 0)
       {   
           if ((flags & WebSocket::FRAME_OP_BITMASK) == WebSocket::FRAME_OP_BINARY)
           {   
               // process and send out to all other clients
           }   
       }   
   }   

}
```

Comment: In example: `Poco::Net::Socket::SELECT_READ || Poco::Net::Socket::SELECT_ERROR` should be `Poco::Net::Socket::SELECT_READ | Poco::Net::Socket::SELECT_ERROR` as `||` will do bolean operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next steps depend on what you are trying to do. Once connected, you have an open channel that you can use for two-way data exchange between browser and server.

For details, see the [WebSocketServer example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/WebSocketServer/src/WebSocketServer.cpp).